# Writing large number of large lists to a file

Tags: python, list, algorithm, performance, file

I wanted to test the efficiency of an algorithm, so I decided to make a text file which contains all the input test cases. My main goal is to make two non intersecting lists which have max size of 10^5. So the simplest way was to make two lists.

- list 1 will begin from 0 and go till 99999
- list 2 will begin from -100000 and go till -1

So the first set of lists will be

list1: -100000

list2: 0

Second set will be

list1: -100000 -99999

list2: 0 1

and it will proceed further till 10^5th iteration

list1: -100000 -99999 ... -1

list2: 0 1 ... 99999

So I wrote this code

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

ip = open("input.dat", "w+")

for length in range(1, 10**5+1):
    arr1 = [var1 for var1 in range(length)]
    arr2 = [var2-(10**5) for var2 in range(length)]
    ip.writelines(["%s " % item  for item in arr1])
    ip.writelines("\n")
    ip.writelines(["%s " % item  for item in arr2])
    ip.writelines("\n\n")

ip.close()
```

But this is highly inefficient, and would take a long time to process. Is there any efficient way to do the same?

Comment: You probably don't want to create a new list at each write. Append the previous list with the missing items instead. Also, appending a space to each number seems unnecessary.  Is there a reason for this?

Comment: @PharoahJardin thanks for the reply... If I dont change the contents of the list again and again, I can't make multiple lists, also spaces are for a specific reason(input format for algo). BTW your answer made me think of a way to try it, I could generate a single list of size 10^5 and then using it, I can directly write its sublists to the file, does that seem as a viable solution, but that only improves memory efficiency, not time efficiency right?

Comment: Sure, that would work. But writing a series of consecutive integers into a file seems unnecessary, too. Can't you just iterate through a range in your algorithm itself?

Comment: So I tried running a modified version of your code (appending to a list instead) but it still hasn't finished running so I guess it still is highly inefficient haha

Comment: @PharoahJardin as I said, it is for testing purposes only and I want it in a dat file, so that I could refere back to it later. Yes very well we could go through  the range in the algo itself, but that's not my purpose. Well I hope there is a way out. Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: I'm not sure if you realise this but your .dat file will exceed 100GB in size! I would highly advise not to continue in this direction.

Comment: @maymay: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on they grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is more efficient but still useless for the `10**5` case.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

ip = open("input.dat", "w+")

N = 10**4

string_arr1 = ""
string_arr2 = ""
for lenght in range(0, N):
    string_arr1 += "%s " % lenght
    string_arr2 += "%s " % (lenght-N)
    ip.write(string_arr1 + "\n")
    ip.write(string_arr2 + "\n\n")

ip.close()
```

On my machine, it runs under 2 seconds.

Edit: corrected a few bugs.

Comment: Very effective approach. You should use `"%s "` for compatibility with the OP's code.

Comment: Hi, thanks. When would the `\n` be written then ? I think it's compatible with OP's code if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: The OP separates the number with a space and adds a newline after the first list and 2 newlines after the second.

Comment: Yeah, but he uses the `.writelines()` method which inserts newlines between items. I use the `.write()` method so I need to compensate by manually appending `\n`.

Comment: contrary to common sense, `.writelines()` does not insert newlines between items, not does it append a newline after the last item. It merely iterates over its argument and writes the elements to the output file.

Comment: Didn't know that! Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear whether you want arrays with 1000 or 100000 items: 10<sup>5</sup> is 100000, not 10000 as mentioned in your question.

You do not need to create intermediary arrays. Just iterate on integer variables. I get a 23% reduction in elapsed time (29.1s vs 37.7s) for 10000 elements with this code:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python

# iterating to 10**4 generates a 538,995,000 byte file (539MB)
# iterating to 10**5 would produce more than 100x that much
max = 10000

ip = open("input.dat", "w+")

for length in range(1, max+1):
    ip.writelines(["%s " % item  for item in range(length)])
    ip.writelines("\n")
    ip.writelines(["%s " % item  for item in range(-max, length-max)])
    ip.writelines("\n\n")

ip.close()
```

The time is spent converting the array items to strings and writing to the file. Creating the arrays is quicker, especially when the creation is delayed as is the case here. `ip.writelines` takes an iterable object, which might not be constructed at all.

Comment: Hey there, thanks for pointing out the error in the question. Made changes... And thanks for the solution...